# How can I modify footer properties in Bootstrap 5 to avoid overlapping content in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: html, .net-core, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I am learning ASP.NET Core MVC and I build a page in which footer overlapping the content.

I have inspect the page and try to change to properties of a footer position from absolute to relative as you can see in the picture.
And the page display as I expected:

[image: I have inspect the page and try to change to properties of a footer position from absolute to relative as you can see in the picture. And the page display as I expected.]

The question is how can I change it in my code?

In my code:

[image]

And I have tried to search the CSS file. And I don't know how to change properties of the footer.

Thanks in advance.